# Plot characteristics with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i reproduce this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6thrh.png
with tikz?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={ft=0.1;
xl(\t)=\t+1;xr(\t)=0.5*\t+2;xc(\t)=1+sqrt(2*\t);}]
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,5);
 \draw[red,semithick,name path=pl] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2,smooth] ({xl(\t)},{\t});
 \draw[red,semithick,name path=pr] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2,smooth] ({xr(\t)},{\t});
 \draw[red,semithick,name path=pc] plot[variable=\t,domain=2:4,smooth] ({xc(\t)},{\t});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The function `u` is not well-defined if `1+\sqrt{2t} \ne 1+t`.

Comment: t > 0 and we take the minimum between 1+t and 1+\sqrt(2t), it's the solution of https://i.imgur.com/L4hVSNw.png

Comment: Take `t>2`, e.g. `t=5`. Then you have `min(1+t,1+\sqrt(2t})=1+\sqrt{2t}`. The function is not (uniquely) defined in the range above `1+\sqrt{2t}`, also `1+t<x<t/2+2` seems to imply that `1+x<t/2+2`, which is not true for all `t`.

Comment: if you take t = 5 then x > 1+sqrt(2t)  u is basically constant

Comment: Well, I thought the function had something to do with the plot you want to produce. However, I am unable to implement the function into Ti*k*Z since it is not well-defined. If you have an approximate but well-defined function/prescription that allows one to produce the output you wish to obtain, this is fine, too. It could be that the only missing information is what values `t` can take.

Comment: The only condition i have on `t` is to be strictly positive

Comment: It's actually like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843118/method-of-characteristics-for-burgers-equation-with-rectangular-data but with different boundaries for x in the initial conditions and u afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, I really do not want to bother you but https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843118/method-of-characteristics-for-burgers-equation-with-rectangular-data does not have overlapping intervals.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try plotting it by separating the 4 domains